# Festival error when trying to use SayText

Tags: text-to-speech, festival

When I enter Festival via the command:

```
festival -q
```

and attempt to utilize SayText, I get the following error:

```
festival> (SayText "hello")
SIOD ERROR: unbound variable : SayText
```

Why does this happen? I thought Festival came equipped with SayText. Do I need to install something else in order to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies in the "-q" you passed to festival when you launched the interactive shell. The man pages state that "-q Load no default setup files", which is causing SayText to not be bound.

I suggest you run your test exactly as follows:

```
$ festival
```

Which will launch festival in interaction mode, prefacing your shell with "festival>"

At this point you can run your SayText command like so:

```
$ (SayText "hello)
```